# Draw line from one div to another on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What's the best way using css, javascript or jquery to draw a simple line on hover from one div to another ?

Thanks a lot for examples.

I have found this code :

```
    h2 > a {
      position: relative;
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    h2 > a:hover {
      color: #000;
    }

    h2 > a:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #000;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

    h2 > a:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
```

from http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/

But I don't know exactly how to modify it to get the wanted solution...

Comment: Where's your code? With 2k+ rep, you should know how to ask a question properly.

Comment: It's ok, sorry for the bad question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can achieve that with CSS . Adjust to suit your needs.

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: realtive;
  cursor: pointer;
   
}

hr {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
  right: -50px;
   left: -300px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 3px;
   background: orange;
   border: none;
    transition: all 3s;
}

.box:hover hr {
     width: 200px;
     transition: all 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
    
    <hr>
</div>

<div class="box"></div> <br> <br>

Hover on the left box
```

Comment: Thanks Sleek Geek, that seems to be a good start point to me, which css attribute have I to edit to start the animation exactly from one box to another (from left to right box)?

Comment: You can reduce the size of your code by using an 'hr' for the line. Extend the width from where you want it to start to where you want it to end, then reduce the width. Extend the width to reach the desired length when the trigger element is hovered.

Answer (score 1):

```
                basic way:

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
            <style>
            div {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px ;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:30px;
}

div:hover + hr{
    display:block !important;
    animation: .5s forwards hover-v linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
hr{
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-top:50px
}



            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="div1">1</div>
    <hr style="display:none">
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <hr style="display:none">
            </body>
            </html>
```